# What if I want to pass same object in different events in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, events

I am working on event driven things and Spring Boot Application Events. I have 2 questions about it.

So I created some basic classes such as (basic hotel reservation app)

Model Class

```
public class HotelBookRequest {
  private String userID;
  private String hotelID;


  public String getUserID() {
      return userID;
  }

  public void setUserID(String userID) {
     this.userID = userID;
  }

  public String getHotelID() {
      return hotelID;
  }

  public void setHotelID(String hotelID) {
      this.hotelID = hotelID;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return "HotelBookRequest{" +
            "userID='" + userID + '\'' +
            ", hotelID='" + hotelID + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

API

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/book")
public class BookingApi {
    @Autowired
    ReservationService reservationService;
    @PostMapping
    public void bookHotel(@RequestBody HotelBookRequest hotelBookRequest){
        System.out.println("Request Processing...");
        reservationService.publishReservationEvent(hotelBookRequest);
        reservationService.publishMsgEvent(hotelBookRequest);
    }


}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class ReservationService {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    public void publishReservationEvent(HotelBookRequest hotelBookRequest){
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(hotelBookRequest);
    }

    public void publishMsgEvent(HotelBookRequest hotelBookRequest){
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(hotelBookRequest);
    }

}
```

and Event Listener

```
@Component
public class ReservationEventListener {

    @Autowired
    ReservationService service;

    @Async
    @EventListener
    public void reservationEventHandler(HotelBookRequest hotelBookRequest) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("1st Event");
    }
    @Async
    @EventListener
    public void msgEventHandler(HotelBookRequest hotelBookRequest){
        System.out.println("2nd Event");
    }

}
```

So, as you see, I have 2 events in Service class and 2 event listeners in Event Listener class.
If I give HotelBookRequest object to the one of Service functions, it calls 2 event listeners. I mean, if I call `reservationService.publishReservationEvent(hotelBookRequest);` it triggers 2 event listeners and gives me output such as

```
1st Event
2nd Event
```

and if I call `reservationService.publishMsgEvent(hotelBookRequest);` it gives me also same output. I can understand why it behaves like that.

1. But, my main question is, what if I want to call api functions with
   the exactly same object without duplicate outputs? What is the logic
   about it?
2. 2nd question is,  What should I do when I want to trigger an
   event from another event? Does it create a dependency on it? What is the most efficient way to trigger nested events?

Comment: Regarding 1. you are not calling API functions, you are publishing events. If there are multiple handlers/listeners for the event, all of them will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 1.
Do you want to make two concurrent API requests?
In this case, to ensure that the hotel will be booked only once, you should look at optimistic/pessimistic locking.

Regarding 2.
It really depends what do the logic that will emit nested event.
For sure you can take a look at the [outbox pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html) if you want to ensure that operation will be transactional and eventually consistent

Comment: Actually, as a simple example, I want to publish 2 events, 1 of them prints out parameter (just for an example) and another one prints out of time. But, when I published 2 events, 2 event listeners called 2 times each. Expected 1 time for each